# SQL Performance-wise, what's better: an IF...ELSE clause, or WHERE LIKE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that has a optional parameter, `@UserID VARCHAR(50)`. The thing is, there are two ways to work with it:

1. Give it a default value of `NULL`, the have an `IF...ELSE` clause, that performs two different `SELECT` queries, one with `'WHERE UserID = @UserID'` and without the where.
2. Give it a default value of `'%'` and then just have the where clause use `'WHERE UserID LIKE @UserID'`. In the calling code, the '%' wont be used, so only exact matches will be found.

The question is: Which option is faster? Which option provides better performance as the table grows? Be aware that the `UserID` column is a foreign key and is not indexed.

**EDIT:** Something I want to add, based on some answers: The `@UserID` parameter is not (necessarily) the only **optional** parameter being passed. In some cases there are as many as 4 or 5 optional parameters.

Comment: I'm begging you... don't go with the answer you accepted. It's a seductive road that leads to pain and misery.

Comment: Mark, i read your answer and you have convinced me. The only thing now, as mentioned in another comment: How do you handle multiple optional parameters? The way it's done now in our DB is to concatenate a WHERE string, add that to the SQL string and call EXEC() on that. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Another option is writing code that writes code. If you need 5 distinct PLANS, write a program that generates those 5 SQL and the case statements that determine which sql does which variable group. But don't run your metacode, take the output and check that in to CVS. the metacode is for your use.

Comment: I think that's not so clear. When people write really cool code that modifies itself on the fly, it's virtually impossible to maintain. Instead, run this cool metacode to produce the code that ultimately gets checked in. This code can be checked in as a separate proj but don't run it in Production.

Answer (score 7):

What I typically do is something like

```
WHERE ( @UserID IS NULL OR UserID = @UserID )
```

And why isn't it indexed? It's generally good form to index FKs, since you often join on them...

If you're worried about query plan storage, simply do:
CREATE PROCEDURE ... WITH RECOMPILE

Comment: Before SQL Server 2008 SP1 CU5 this is terrible. If you are on a later version adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the query makes this a viable way of implementing dynamic search conditions. (As researched by Erland Sommarskog)

Answer (score 3):

The only way to tell for sure is to implement both and measure. For reference there is a third way to implement this, which is what I tend to use:

```
WHERE (@UserID IS NULL OR UserId = @UserId)
```

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server 2005 and subsequent have something called "statement-level recompilation". Check out 
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/sql/2005/recomp.mspx

Basically, each individual statement executed by the query processor gets it's own optimized plan, which is then stored in "Plan Cache"  (This is why they changed the name from "Procedure-Cache")

So branching your T-SQL into separate statements is better...

Answer (score 2):

Why not use:

```
where @UserID is null or UserID=@UserID
```

+ on maintainability and performance

Comment: Are you forcing a hard parse each and every time?

Comment: No- optimizier should factor that out.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with having only one stored procedure is as mentioned quite well above that the SQL stores a compiled plan for the procedure, a plan for null is quite different to one with a value.

However, creating an if statement in the stored procedure will lead to the stored procedure being recompiled at run time. This may also add to the performance issues.

As mentioned elsewhere, this is suitable for a test and see approach, taking into account the if statement, an @UserID is null and two separate procedures.

Unfortunately, the speed of these approaches is going to vary greatly based on the amount of data and the frequency of the calls where the parameter is null vs the calls where the parameter is not. Again the number of parameters is also going to affect the efficacy of an approach that requires re-writing the procedures.

If you are using SQL 2005, you may get some mileage from the query [plan hint option](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/sql/2005/frcqupln.mspx).

**Correction:**
Sql 2005 and since has "statement-Level Recompilation" which store separate plans in cache for each statement in a procedure... So the old Pre-2005 policy of not putting multiple logic branch statements into a single stored procedure is no longer true...  – Charles Bretana 
(i figure this was important enough to elevate from a comment)

Comment: Sql 2005 and since has "statement-Level Recompilation" which  store separatye plans in cache for each statement in a procedure... So the old Pre-2005 policy of not putting multiple logic branch statements into a single stored procedure is no longer true...

Answer (score 1):

I'd defiantly go with the first because although it's less 'clever' it's easier to understand what's going on and will hence be easier to maintain.

The use of the special meaning default is likely to trip you up later with some unintended side-effect (documentation as to why you're using that default and it's usage is likely to be missed by any maintainer)

As to efficiency - unless you're looking at 1,000 users or more then it's unlikely to be sufficient an issue to override maintainability.

Comment: I could kiss you. But don't give in to bad habits because the data may be small... if he does it where it won't matter, he'll continue to do it were it does matter and be hosed.

Comment: Aye, I'll avoid the kissing but actually I meant the other way around - always go for clear obvious code unless performance issues *force* you otherwise AND always remember that machine cycles are far cheaper than coder cycles.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should create an index for `UserID` if you use it as a search criteria in this way.

Second, comparing `UserID LIKE @UserID` cannot use an index, because the optimizer doesn't know if you will give a `@UserID` parameter value that begins with a wildcard.  Such a value cannot use the index, so the optimizer must assume it cannot create an execution plan using that index.

So I recommend:

1. Create an index on `UserID`
2. Use the first option, `WHERE UserID = @UserID`, which should be optimized to use the index.

**edit:** Mark Brady reminds me I forgot to address the `NULL` case.  I agree with Mark's answer, do the `IF` and execute one of two queries.  I give Mark's answer +1.

Comment: And when there is no User_ID, when he wants them all? You haven't fully answered the question. You handled the half that's simple.

Comment: Where UserId Like @UserId WILL use an index, if one is available, as long as the value of @UserID Does not include a wild card at the BEGINNING of the string value ... as in 
Where lastname Like '%higgins' 
If you had 
Where LastName Like 'Higgins'  Or 
Where LastName Like 'Higgins%' Then its ok

Comment: @Charles: as I understand it, that would require recompiling the execution plan with respect to the given value of @UserID.  Otherwise the optimizer may not be able to assume it can use the index.

Comment: No more so than when using Where UserId = @UserId for a new different value of @UserID... The optimizer has to look at the statistics to see how many Page IOs would be required to rtead those pages from disk using the index, as compared to doing a FTS... Using :Like, without leading wildcards,

Comment: it can traverse the index in exactly the same way as it would if you were using Where UserId = ....

Comment: Very good to know.  I admit I don't use MS SQL much, as I do other database brands.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replace the single stored procedure with two. There's way to much room for the query optimizer to start whacking you with unintended consequence on this one. Change the client code to detect which one to call.

I bet if you had done it that way, we wouldn't need to be having this dialog.

And put an index on userid. Indexes are in there for a reason, and this is it.

Answer (score 0):

I would sort-of go with option 1, but actually have two stored procedures.  One would get all the users and one would get a specific user.  I think this is clearer than passing in a NULL.  This is a scenario where you do want two different SQL statements because you're asking for different things (all rows vs one row).

Comment: I could do that, although: 1. The WHERE clause may still return more than one row, 2. There are additional optional parameters, and 3. It's easier on the logic in the code to have one SP and only pass the neccessary parameters.

Comment: I've used the NULL-means-everything approach before and been burnt when buggy code passes in NULL for everything.  Then the database goes off and fetches a million rows.